# Pycharm - Import Module in Python - Different behaviour - MAC vs Windows

Tags: python, pycharm

My folder structure:

- /backend/webservices.py
- /backend/csv_utilities.py

`webservices.py` starts like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from backend.csv_utilities import *
import os
```

- If I run `webservices.py`on MAC, I won't have any problems.
- If I run `webservices.py`on Windows, I will get a module not found error.

Changing `webservices.py` like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from csv_utilities import *
import os
```

works **on both**; MAC and Windows. But in PyCharm (on MAC, I didn't try on Windows) now I get an error marked on `csv_utilities`and it says: unresolved reference 'csv_utilities'.

Why is this error there? I can run it without problems. Is it a Pycharm issue or am I doing something not in the right way?

Comment: i am going to try now on mac pycharm and let you know

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exact Python versions are you using on each platform? What is the environment of the interpreter? Can you reproduce from the command line or only in PyCharm? As it stands, you haven't provided enough information for someone to help you solve the problem.

Comment: @DanielPryden Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on MAC, Python 3.6.5 (from python.org) on Windows. On MAC both versions work (from command line), on Windows only the last version works (from command line).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue once. Try **Mark directory as Sources Root** option on your **backend** folder. It worked for me.

Comment: This solves the issue, that PyCharm marks it as an error. but I still don't know why the first snippet works only on MAC and the second one works on Windows and MAC